# Linq FirstOrDefault - one liner

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

i have the following code to determine a age from a `Person`

```
var pList = ctx.Person.Where(x => x.Create > Date);
int Age = pList.Where(x => x.ID == "foo").FirstOrDefault().Age ?? 20;
```

I pick a `Person` by ID, if it doesn't exist the default value is 20.

The 2nd line is invalid, because Age can't be null but Person can be. Is there a way to get this working in **one line**? I've tried with DefaultIfEmpty but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What C# version are you using?

Comment: Is this for Entity framework?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the overload of [`Enumerable.DefaultIfEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
int Age = pList
    .Where(x => x.ID == "foo")
    .Select(x => x.Age)
    .DefaultIfEmpty(20)
    .First();
```

As you can see, `FirstOrdefault` is not necessary anymore since the default value is taken if the input sequence is empty(the id-filter returned no persons).

Comment: The only answer in the thread that answers OP's question (including requirements of one-liner and C# version)

Answer (score 5):

```
int Age = pList.Where(x => x.ID == "foo").FirstOrDefault()?.Age ?? 20;
```

Only in C# 6.

For those in suspicion:
[image]

Comment: Will this work? `Age` is a regular (non-nullable) integer. As far as I am aware, C# 6 doesn't change the `??` operator.

Comment: @rmorrin The null conditional operator (`?.Age`) will change the return type to `int?`, so the following `??` works fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```
int Age = pList.Where(x => x.ID == "foo").Select(x=>(int?)x.Age).FirstOrDefault() ?? 20;
```

Comment: Very nice approach :) Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty, by any means, but you wanted to do it as short as possible, while still counting for several potential NullPointerExceptions. Please dont do this in a one liner, and please dont make the int nullable to acheive that. The code below is not pretty, and not tested as i don't have the possibility at the moment.

Note that i would recommend doing it differently, with the long hand if statements, for zero code repetition and readability.

```
Person person = ctx.Person.Where(x => x.Create > Date && x.ID.Equals("foo")).FirstOrDefault()

int age = (person != null) ? person.Age : 20;
```